# When is $(x \textrm{ mod } a) \textrm{ mod } b = (x \textrm{ mod } b) \textrm{ mod } a$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I don't know when the equation $(x \textrm{ mod } a) \textrm{ mod } b = (x \textrm{ mod } b) \textrm{ mod } a$ holds.

I am looking for non-trivial necessary of sufficient conditions on $a,b$, and $x$. Is there any special conditions when they are in $\mathbb{Z}$  or when they are in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

For now I only found that if $a$ is a multiple of $b$, then it holds for all $x$.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b$ be positive integers with $a\le b$.

**Claim:**$\;$An integer $x$ satisfies the equation
$$
(x\;\text{mod}\;a)\;\text{mod}\;b
=
(x\;\text{mod}\;b)\;\text{mod}\;a
\qquad\;\;\;\;
$$
if and only if
$$
a\,{\Large{\mid}}\!\left(b\left\lfloor{\small{\frac{x}{b}}}\right\rfloor\right)
$$
**Proof:**

Fix positive integers $a,b$ with $a\le b$, and let $x$ be an integer.

Let $r=x\;\text{mod}\;a$ and let $s=x\;\text{mod}\;b$.

By the division algorithm, we get 
$$
r=x-a\left\lfloor{\small{\frac{x}{a}}}\right\rfloor
\\
s=x-b\left\lfloor{\small{\frac{x}{b}}}\right\rfloor
$$
Since $0\le r < a$ and $a\le b$ it follows that $r\;\text{mod}\;b=r$, hence
\begin{align*}
&
(x\;\text{mod}\;a)\;\text{mod}\;b
=
(x\;\text{mod}\;b)\;\text{mod}\;a
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
r\;\text{mod}\;b=s\;\text{mod}\;a
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
r=s\;\text{mod}\;a
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
s\equiv r\;(\text{mod}\;a)\qquad\text{[since $0\le r < a$]}
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
x-b\left\lfloor{\small{\frac{x}{b}}}\right\rfloor
\equiv
x-a\left\lfloor{\small{\frac{x}{a}}}\right\rfloor
\;(\text{mod}\;a)
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
b\left\lfloor{\small{\frac{x}{b}}}\right\rfloor
\equiv
0
\;(\text{mod}\;a)
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
a\,{\Large{\mid}}\!\left(b\left\lfloor{\small{\frac{x}{b}}}\right\rfloor\right)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you very much good sir ^^